# Using External CSS Files with iText 7 ConvertToPdf

Tags: css, itext7

Hello everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I am new to iText 7 and am learning to convert web pages to pdf.  The code looks like:

```
            string url = "http://mypage.com";

        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        Stream myStream = myWebClient.OpenRead(url);

        string dest = @"E:\HTMLToPDF.pdf";
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(myStream, new System.IO.FileStream(dest, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
```

The page uses external style sheets that do not render under the current code,  However, when I run a replace with the retrieved page to add the fully qualified path to the style sheets (i.e. http://mypage.com/styles/style.css instead of styles/style.css) the page generates correctly.  Is this something I need to incorporate into the code to generate the pdf, or is there another method within iText to handle this.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `ConverterProperties` object that tells `pdfHTML`
(using setBaseURI) where to look for external resources.

```
  // writer
  PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(getOutputFile());
  PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
  pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(1000f, 1450f));

 // convert
 ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
 converterProperties.setBaseUri("base_uri_here");

 HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(getInputFiles()[0]), pdfDocument, converterProperties);
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the help.